# how to run c#4.0(visual studio 2010) windows desktop application in linux?

Tags: linux, c#-4.0

I want to run c#4.0 windows Desktop application in linux?Please anybody having idea share with me...

Saravanan.P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to run C# code on linux is to use the Mono project: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

But maybe all the Framework 4.0 is not yet ported. You have to test to compile your application against Mono.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Cross-Platform" procedure. It will help you.

Use the Visual Studio .NET IDE and Grasshopper to Deploy .NET Apps on Linux!

> http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=45

Comment: If you are using VB.NET in Visual Studio then surely your target platform is Windows?

Generally it is best to develop your program on the same platform as the target.

However if you really want to use VB.NET on Linux then try researching SharpDevelop and/or MonoDevelop.

Comment: If you are really wanting to run Visual Studio on Linux, then you could look into the CodeWeavers software. 

Looking at their compatibility list, they list up to Visual Studio 2008.